# How to get blob from local file url in angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, blob

I'm trying to get BLOB from local file URL. This is my code.

```js
let url ="file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/AssetInfoXMLOxk!B1568355279906/1568355272623.jpeg";
fetch(url).then((res) => res.blob()).then((blob) => {
  console.log(blob);
})
```

Unfortunately i'm not able get blob because of this error. 
 **from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, https.**
How can I get blob from local file URL? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show `fetch(url)`

Comment: @AdritaSharma. file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/AssetInfoXMLOxk!B1568355279906/1568355272623.jpeg

Comment: Show the function!!

Comment: @AdritaSharma. I have already added code in snippet. fetch(url).then((res) => res.blob()).then((blob) => {
  console.log(blob);
})

Comment: Go to defination of `fetch`

Comment: @AdritaSharma. Are there any other ways to get BLOB from local url?

Comment: Yes. There is..

Comment: @AdritaSharma. Can you please give me the source?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe((resp: any) => {
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this works form me, I am using file saver to save file in angular.

downlode_file.service:->

```
    downlode_file() {
     const downlode_file_url = "url"
      let headers = new Headers({ 
        'Content-Type':'application/json', 
        'Accept': 'application/.xls' //give file extension
     });
     let options = { headers : headers };
      return this.http.post(downlode_file_url,options,{responseType: "blob"});
    }
```

components.ts:->

```
this.downlode_file.downlode_file().subscribe((file: Blob) => {
  FileSaver.saveAs(file,'filename.xls');
  console.log("Downloaded Successfully...")
}, (err) => {
  console.log("Download Error:", err);
});
```